# Dense subgroup of a compact connected Lie group generated by two words

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and $w_1$, $w_2$ be two *positive* words in alphabet  $\{a, b\}$ which are not the powers of some another word $w$. *Positive* means that $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ can not be used.

For example the pair $w_1=ab$ and $w_2=ba$ is allowed. And the pair $w_1=ababab$ and $w_2=abab$ is not allowed. The pair $w_1=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $w_2=a$ is also not allowed, as $w_1$ is not positive.

Question: is it true that for a typical ( with respect to the Haar measure on $G$) pair $(a, b)\in G^2$ the subgroup generated by $w_1(a,b)$ and $w_2(a,b)$ is dense in $G$?

Comment: For which pairs do you know this to hold (apart from pairs generating $F_2$)? or for which $G$ (other than the easy abelian cases)?

Comment: @YCor, I know only these two easy cases. But I guess for pairs like $w_1=a^2b$, $w_2=b^5$ it should be eassily reducible to these easy cases, even though formally these words do not generate $F_2$. What is of interest is some $\textit{non-trivial pairs}$ whatever "nontrivial" means, like, for example $w_1=ab$, $w_2=ba$.

Comment: $SO(3)$ should be easy anyway for $(ab,ba)$, because the list of proper closed subgroups is short. Namely, if $\langle ab,ba\rangle$ is not dense, then $(ab)^{60}$ and $(ba)^{60}$ commute (indeed either $ab,ba$ preserve a common axis hence their squares commute, or $ab,ba$ generate a tetrahedral/cubic/icosahedral group, whose order divides $60$). Just exhibiting a pair $(a,b)$ for which this fails shows that $(ab,ba)$ is generically topologically generating (actually, for all $a,b$ in the Zariski-open subset $\{a,b:[(ab)^{60},(ba)^{60}]\neq 1\}$).

Comment: @YCor, sure, by 'non-trivial pair' I mean a pair for which the statement ( if true) does not immediately follow by some obvious general reasons, like for $G$ abelian or for a pair generating $F_2$.

Comment: Well you didn't specify this reason and that $SO(3)$ can be dealt with (and hence its powers too), which you summarize as "a pair generating $F_2$" but is not exactly this. The special fact of $SO(3)$ is that there is a common law satisfied by all proper closed subgroups but not by $SO(3)$ itself. So, in order to converge, I understand that what you call "trivial case", say for $(ab,ba)$, is the case when $G$ is locally isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^k\times\mathrm{SO}(3)^\ell$ for some $(k,\ell)$.

Comment: @YCor The point is that I do not have any specific pairs in my hands. The only control which I have over the pair is the condition specified in the original question. But of course for a precisely given pair ( which unfortunately I do not have) one can try ( as you did right now) to give a specific ( for this pair) proof.

Comment: My argument is not specific to this pair: it works for an arbitrary non-commuting pair $w_1,w_2$ in $F_2$. But only for $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ (and hence all $G$ with only $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ simple factors— let's focus on $G$ simple since it's enough). For given $(w_1,w_2,G)$, is the question equivalent to the question of barely asking the existence of $(a,b)\in G^2$ such that $\langle w_1(a,b),w_2(a,b)\rangle$ is dense?

Comment: @YCor Interesting, thank you. Even though still the case of general $G$ is of interest. The question is little more than just existence. The question is whether that such pairs $(a, b)$ form a $\textit{full measure set}$ in $G^2$.

Comment: I guess that in a compact connected semisimple Lie group $G$, there are finitely many maximal closed proper subgroups up to conjugation, and that the set $\Xi_G\subset G^2$ of pairs $(a,b)$ belonging to one of those is Zariski-closed. If so, one has the alternative, for given $w_1,w_2$: either the induced map $G^2\to G^2$, mapping $(a,b)$ to $(w_1(a,b),w_2(a,b))$ maps into $\Xi_G$, or the inverse image of $\Xi_G$ is a proper Zariski-closed subset. If so (this is maybe known), the question whether the set of pairs has full measure is the same as asking whether it's non-empty.

Comment: @YCor: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118764740

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why do you point out this reference? I'm aware that $G$ has a topologically generating pair, but this just says that $\Xi_G\neq G$. I see that Lemma 3 says that $\Xi_G$ is closed in the ordinary topology, but in the compact case this is immediate if we have finiteness of the number of maximal subgroups mod conjugation. Actually $\Xi_G$ can have non-empty interior, e.g., when $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, and the link doesn't say anything specific to $G$ compact.

Comment: @Ycor I see what you mean.  Independent remark: As a matter of fact for more delicate applications ( this is related to pseudorandom walks on  G, generated by some particular type of dynamical systems) it might be needed somewhat more delicate information on these pairs than just full measure, but so far at least full measure would be enough..

Comment: @Ycor actually in the particular situation which I did (for surfaces of genus one and two) the words which appear do generate $F_2$ but I have no idea how to prove it in more general situation ( any genus). So the condition in the question is something I believe I can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

See the result of [Gerstenhaber-Rothaus](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.48.9.1531), which says that if the abelianization of the word map has full rank, then the map $G\times G\to G\times G$ has non-zero degree. This is a necessary condition, as one can see if $G$ is abelian or has an abelian quotient (e.g. $U(n)$). 
So this won't apply to $\{ab,ba\}$.

Once the map is non-zero degree, the pushforward of the Haar measure on $G\times G$ should be [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) with respect to Haar measure. This is because the map is also algebraic, and hence the preimage of points are smaller dimension, so the preimage of a set of measure $0$ will be measure $0$.

A theorem of Weyl implies that a compact subgroup of an algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$ is an algebraic subgroup. Now we follow the argument in [Barnea-Larsen](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303006434), section 3.

*Barnea, Y.; Larsen, M.*, [**Random generation in semisimple algebraic groups over local fields.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2002.12.001), J. Algebra 271, No. 1, 1-10 (2004). [ZBL1049.20028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1049.20028).

Let's assume that $G$ is semisimple; I think that the general case can be reduced to this case. Since $G$ is compact, we may complexify to get a semisimple algebraic group $G^{\mathbb{C}}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. By Lemma 3.2, there is a countable set $\{X_0,X_1,\ldots\}$ of proper closed subvarieties such that if $\gamma\in G^{\mathbb{C}}- \cup_i X_i(\mathbb{C})$, then the Zariski closure of $\gamma$ is a maximal torus. Passing to $G=G^{\mathbb{R}}$, the real subgroup, we see that the same is true for $G$. Hence with probability $1$, any element $\gamma\in G$ will have closure a maximal torus.

Proposition 3.3 states that there is a proper closed subvariety $X \subset G^{\mathbb{C}}\times G^{\mathbb{C}}$ so that for any proper algebraic subgroup $H$ containing a maximal torus, $H\times H \subset X$.

Now choose a random pair of elements $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)\in G\times G$ with respect to a measure absolutely continuous with respect to Haar measure. Then with probability $1$, $\overline{\langle\gamma_i\rangle}$ is a maximal torus, since $\cup_i{X_i(\mathbb{R})}$ has measure $0$. Then if $\langle \gamma_1,\gamma_2\rangle$ is not dense in $G$, then $\overline{\langle \gamma_1,\gamma_2\rangle}=H < G$, where $H$ is closed and contains a maximal rank torus. So $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)\in X$, again occurring with probability $0$.

I think this gives an outline of a proof under these assumptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer. The problem though is that I have very little control over the possible words. They appear from some dynamics on higher genus surfaces ( and I do not fix the genus) and the conditions formulated in the original question are the only ones which I can currently prove, this is why I formulated it this way. However your answer made me think if I can establish full rank of abelinization. I did not think about it and that might be possible after extra-work.. however not guaranteed..

Comment: @DmitriScheglov: Part of the argument goes through in your case, I think: with probability 1, $\gamma_i$ will be Zariski dense in a maximal torus by the Gerstenhaber-Rothaus argument (because $\gamma_i$ has non-zero exponent sum, so we can pair it with another element giving something of non-zero degree to $G\times G$, then project to the first coordinate). So then you need the map to avoid the set $X$ again. This seems quite plausible to me under your assumption.

Comment: let me think about it..

Comment: You might be able to compute the derivative of the map at the identity (which should be a map between Lie algebras) to show that the image of the map doesn't lie in the subgroups H, and hence not lying in the subvariety X.

Comment: I will try to see.. May be it makes sense to see first how it works at least for {ab, ba}..